# Problem using data struct with class object

Tags: swiftui

Newbie here.  My code is pretty simple and the problem is likely very simple, as well...
I have a data struct and am using a class to house arrays of these data structs.  I'm using a class and ObservableObject because there will be child views from this parent view.

```
struct UserData: Identifiable
    {
       var id = UUID()
       var name = String()
    }

``
class User: ObservableObject
{
   @Published var userDataArray = [UserData]()

   init(userDataArray: [UserData])
   {
    self.userDataArray = userDataArray
   }
}
``


struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var user = User(userDataArray: [])
```

```
var body: some View {

TextField("Name", text: $user.name)
```

I get an error message saying, "Value of type 'ObservedObject.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'name' using key path from root type 'User'".

I've tried $user.userDataArray.name as well with a similar error message`.
TYIA

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Your `User` has an _array_ of `UserData`. So, if you want to have a `TextField` hooked up to a single user's name, you need to get an item out of the array first. Maybe this will help? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-list-or-a-foreach-from-a-binding

Comment: Please be more careful with the naming of your objects. Rename `UserData` as `User`, `User` as `ViewModel` and `var user` as`var model` then the error becomes obvious. There is no `name` property in the `ObservableObject`, not even in `userDataArray` because an array contains multiple items.

Comment: You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Comment: OK.  I'll explain what I'm ultimately trying to do - that TextField will be on a sheet.  The user enters their name.  Hits save.  On this parent view (ContentView), the name will be displayed as Text.  So I currently have a data struct and a class to hold arrays of each user's data.

Comment: The video I mentioned above has your answer, you need a ForEach but you are also missing the basics it is overall something you need to see.

Comment: Thanks for the video and the help.  I'm actually going to simplify my code to get rid of the array.  A data entry sheet with TextFields that when saved populate text (string interpolation) on the parent view.  So, for now it'll only be able to save and display one user.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a list view with a ForEach but went with that pattern anyway.  It all works now.  Maybe in the future I'll change how the entered data is displayed.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
struct User: Identifiable
{
   let id = UUID()
   var name = ""
}

class UserStore: ObservableObject
{
   @Published var users: [User] = []

   init() {
       // usually this would load from file
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var store = UserStore()
...
        ForEach($store.users) { $user in 
            TextField("Name", text: $user.name)
        }
...
```